# Why can't I connect to a remote private queue in msmq?

Tags: msmq

I've asked this question in the MSDN forum, I got a lot of help there from John Breakwell, but I couldn't solve my issue and now I am running in circles (again). So maybe someone here can help me.

I have a remote private queue, a producer application and a consumer application. I am using Windows Server 2008 with MSMQ.

I can send the message using my producer app, but I can't read it using my consumer. Here is my consumer code

```
MessageQueue rmQ = new MessageQueue("FormatName:Direct=OS:<hostname>\\private$\\<queuename>");
System.Messaging.Message msg = rmQ.Receive();
```

I get an exception in the second line, the exception is null without any information, except for the stack trace

> System.Messaging.MessageQueueException (0x80004005)
>      at System.Messaging.MessageQueue.MQCacheableInfo.get_ReadHandle()
>      at System.Messaging.MessageQueue.StaleSafeReceiveMessage(UInt32 timeout, Int3
>   2 action, MQPROPS properties, NativeOverlapped* overlapped, ReceiveCallback rece
>   iveCallback, CursorHandle cursorHandle, IntPtr transaction)
>      at System.Messaging.MessageQueue.ReceiveCurrent(TimeSpan timeout, Int32 actio
>   n, CursorHandle cursor, MessagePropertyFilter filter, MessageQueueTransaction in
>   ternalTransaction, MessageQueueTransactionType transactionType)
>      at System.Messaging.MessageQueue.Receive()
>      at consumer.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\usr\Documents\Visua
>   l Studio 2010\Projects\loadQueueTest\consumer\Program.cs:line 20

I've read a lot of things, so I have already done somethings:

- I've set the anonymous logon to have full access on the queue
- I've set my domain user as the administrator on the server
- Opened the ports for MSMQ and RPC
- Disabled the Firewall

I also used rpcping and portqry to perform some diagnostics, I am not an expert, but it seems ok.

Does anyone knows what I am missing?

Thanks,
Oscar

Comment: Did you give access for the Anonymous Logon/domain user account to the MSMQ key in the registry (HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSMQ)?

Comment: Oscar, did you get to try all the options in "Understanding how MSMQ security blocks RPC traffic"  
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johnbreakwell/archive/2010/03/24/understanding-how-msmq-security-blocks-rpc-traffic.aspx"

Comment: @JohnBreakwell, Yes, I did and unfortunately it didn't solve my problem

Comment: @Chris no, I didn't. I will try to see if it works and get back to you

Comment: There should be no reason to change the permissions on MSMQ's registry branch. Only the MSMQ service is going to read the values.

Comment: I've had to give permissions to that key for each account my services have ran under that used MSMQ.  If it's a standalone app running under a sysadmin type account or whatnot maybe you don't, I've always wrote these type of apps as windows services that run under a specific user.

Comment: Very curious. I can safely say that in 10 years in MSMQ support, I never needed to ask customers to change registry permissions. Must give it some thought.

Comment: Can I suggest to look at a similar topic here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/376208/connecting-to-a-private-remote-msmq-queue Hope this helps.